# Transpose of a very large matrix with fewer than 1021 rows with Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix of fewer than 1021 rows. I'd like to take its transpose, but it is too big for GNU `datamash` and `awk` solutions to fit into memory.

To keep memory overhead low, my thought is that I keep a list of read-only file pointers to the start of each row. I then read out bytes from each pointer until I hit a delimiter (tab or newline).

Because I have fewer than 1021 rows, I won't hit the usual 1024 OS-based file pointer limit.

Once I have read out a field from all file pointers, I write a newline character and start over, reading a field from all file pointers, and again, until no more bytes are available:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

import sys
import os

try:
  in_fn = sys.argv[1]
except ValueError as ve:
  sys.exit(-1)

def get_size(fn):
  st = os.stat(fn)
  return st.st_size

#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# 1) Read in file offsets to start of new line                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# 2) Open up a file pointer to that offset                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# 3) Process each file pointer to get a value until a delimiter is hit, then write it as a row of output                                                                                                                                            
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

size = get_size(in_fn)

fps = []
new_fp = open(in_fn, 'r')
new_fp.seek(0, 0)
fps.append(new_fp)

with open(in_fn, 'r') as f:
  byte = f.read(1)
  while byte:
    if byte == '\n':
      new_offset = f.tell()
      if new_offset < size:
        new_fp = open(in_fn, 'r')
        new_fp.seek(new_offset, 0)
        fps.append(new_fp)
      else:
        break
    byte = f.read(1)

while size > 0:
  for fi, f in enumerate(fps):
    byte = f.read(1)
    size -= 1
    while byte:
      if byte == '\t' or byte == '\n':
        if fi != len(fps) - 1: sys.stdout.write('\t')
        break
      sys.stdout.write('%s' % (byte))
      byte = f.read(1)
      size -= 1
  sys.stdout.write('\n')

for f in fps:
  f.close()
```

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of this? Reading and processing a set of file pointers one byte at a time seems quite expensive. However, I need to find newline characters to build offsets and file pointers. Is there a cleverer/faster way (in Python) to find the byte offsets of newlines?

Comment: While you did say how many rows your matrix has, you did not specify the number of columns. If that is less than a million or so, reading it all into memory and transposing it there will be faster.

Comment: Have you considered `mmap` and offsets as an alternative to file descriptors?  That might be easier to work with.  It certainly scales to more rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't read the file into memory, otherwise I'd use `datamash` or `awk` if I could. The `mmap` approach looks interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The golden rule of I/O performance is **never read a block twice**.  You're reading each block thousands of times.

I made a thousand-row test file with records of about 2MB each:

```
tr -dc '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom  | fold -w2000000 | head -1000 > test.txt
```

And modified the `fps`-building portion of your code thusly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from prettyprinter import pprint
import sys
import os
import re

try:
  in_fn = sys.argv[1]
except ValueError as ve:
  sys.exit(-1)

sz = os.path.getsize(in_fn)
fps = [ open(in_fn, 'r') ]
bufsz = 100 * 2**20 # MB

with open(in_fn, 'r') as f:
  offset = 0
  buf = f.read(bufsz)
  while len(buf)>0:
    for p in [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'\n', buf)]:
      new_pos = offset+p+1
      if new_pos < sz:
        new_fp = open(in_fn, 'r')
        new_fp.seek(new_pos, 0)
        fps.append(new_fp)

    offset = f.tell()
    buf = f.read(bufsz)

pprint( list( map( lambda f: f.tell(), fps ) ) )
```

This runs 65 times faster than the bytewise version on my machine.

The actual transposition will benefit similarly from this treatment.   Keep a buffer for each row and append to it with a `read` when it's empty.

If you want to keep the logic simpler, you can compromise (with a performance penalty) by reading a few kilobytes at a time and rewind-`seek`ing  the filehandle back to the first tab character.  This would remove the need to keep an array of buffers.

Comment: This appears to be ridiculously faster, in comparison.